# Why my images are being returned with a -90 degrees rotation, using the PptxGenJS library with react.js?

Tags: reactjs, pptxgenjs

I'm using the `PptxGenJS` library in conjunction with `React.js` to generate PowerPoint presentations. However, I've encountered an issue where certain images appear misaligned, as if rotated to -90 degrees, when viewed in the generated presentation. Strangely, when I open the same JPEG images directly in a web browser, they appear correctly oriented. This discrepancy doesn't occur for everyone. Any insights on why this might be happening?

Comment: JPEG images can contain orientation data which instructs the browser/viewer which way to rotate them when displaying them - e.g. https://jdhao.github.io/2019/07/31/image_rotation_exif_info/  seems to have an explanation.